# Fix syntax highlight for Python f"" formatting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

**Hello.**

Since Python 3.6, Python supports f-string formatting ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) and mostly IDEs highlight such as strings different.

**PyCharm:**

[image]

This special highlighting significantly increases readability of code and helps visually divide variables from template text. It would be great to see similar highlighting on Stack Overflow.

**Current highlighting *(for comparison)*:**

[image]

In my opinion, it will be more than enough to keep text between parentheses black color, like this:

[image]

Comment: See the duplicate: direct feature requests to the prettify project